# Para que serve o REPLACE INTO no MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Qual é a finalidade do comando `REPLACE INTO` no MYSQL?

Exemplo:

```
REPLACE INTO tabela(col1, col2) values(value1, value2) WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Como no `INSERT` o `REPLACE` checa se a primary Key é repetida e se estiver ele substitui ao invés de adicionar valores sem checar nada.
Para mais referencias [Documentação do REPLACE MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

O `REPLACE INTO` é interessante.

Vamos imaginar uma tabela:

```
ID   NOME
1    Diego
2    José
```

Quero atualizar o nome do José para José Pedro.

`REPLACE INTO USUARIOS (ID, NOME) VALUES (2, 'José Pedro')`

O comando vai fazer o que?

Informei o nome dos campos no primeiro casal de parênteses, ID e NOME. E no `VALUES` coloquei o ID 2 que se refere ao José e no campo NOME o novo valor que quero que atualize.

O comando irá **atualizar** o registro se ele existir, caso exista o ID 2. Caso o valor do ID seja definido como `NULL` ou `''` será **adicionado** um registro novo.

Ou seja: se o registro existir **atualiza**, se não **insere**.

`REPLACE INTO USUARIOS (ID, NOME) VALUES (NULL, 'Bigown')`

Ficaria assim:

```
ID   NOME
1    Diego
2    José Pedro
3    Bigown
```

### **Observações**

1 - Não é preciso usar o `WHERE` caso seja definido o `ID`.

2 - O ID deve ser `auto_increment`.

3 - Se a tabela possuir mais campos e eles não serem definidos no `INTO` e `VALUES`, os valores serão apagados. Infelizmente é assim.

4 - Dá para contornar o que acontece no ponto 3 com um `SELECT` na mesma tabela. Aí sim é **necessário** o `WHERE` no `SELECT`.

```
REPLACE INTO USUARIOS(ID, NOME, TELEFONE, ENDERECO)
SELECT 2, 'José Pedro dos Santos', TELEFONE 
WHERE ID = 2
```

Comment: O `WHERE`, neste caso, não é necessário?

Comment: @Earendul Bem lembrado, não é necessário, visto já estar como que embutido na coluna ID.

Comment: E se a tabela tiver  um outro campo (telefone por exemplo) e eu não passá-lo para a lista de colunas que serão afetadas? Ele permanecerá e os outros dados serão substituídos?

Comment: Serão todos substituídos. O comando apaga tudo o que não estiver definido.

Comment: O que dá para fazer é um `REPLACE INTO` com um `SELECT`.

Comment: Aproveitando o tópico, não seria mais fácil usar o `UPDATE` ?

Comment: Não, Guilherme. Dependendo do caso, o REPLACE INTO, é mais adequado. Não é a toa que existe esse recurso.

Comment: Na verdade o que acontece quando o registro existe NÃO é um simples Update, mas sim uma AÇÃO DUPLA, sendo executado um DELETE seguido de um INSERT. No caso do exemplo citado pelo do Diego Souza o 'José Pedro' terá o ID=3 porque o 2 será deletado. Por consequencia o 'Bigow' terá o ID=4. Por fim, deve-se ter muita atenção ao utilizar o REPLACE justamente por causa do DELETE pois se sua tabela possuir TRIGGER ou integridade referencial com chave-estrangeira referenciando outra tabela, pode acontecer uma reação em cascata e impactar na performance, ou simplesmente não (deletar) atualizar nada. ;)